# Neo4j group by file hash and link file names associated with each hash

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node(FileName) that is has 2 properties, `name` and `FileHash`.

```
f.name             f.FileHash
"image001.png"     "23a5s6d"
"image002.png"     "56e41s3"
"image003.png"     "6a5s21s"
"image003.png"     "23a5s6d"
"image003.png"     "56e41s3"
"image004.png"     "56e41s3"
"image004.png"     "32a1321"
```

I would like to see the different file attachments that have the same file hash.  It would be strange for files to be with the same file hash but different names.

My desired output would be something like:

[image]

I am trying:

```
MATCH (f:FileName)
WITH f.FileHash as h, COLLECT(f.name) as n
WHERE not h = 'false' AND not n = 'false'
UNWIND n as x
MATCH (h)--(x)
RETURN h,x
```

but I am getting the error:

`Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed: Expected to find a node at 'h' but found String("23a5s6d") instead`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation functions, [`COLLECT`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) in this case

```
MATCH ....
RETURN f.FileHash,COLLECT(f.name)
```

will give you following result:

```
"23a5s6d",["image001.png","image003.png"]
"56e41s3",["image002.png","image003.png","image004.png"]
"6a5s21s",["image003.png"]
"32a1321",["image004.png"]
```

Comment: I like your answer and I see what you did here, but I am having trouble trying to visualize these results. @František Hartman

Comment: I am trying:  
MATCH (f:FileName)
WITH f.FileHash as h, COLLECT(f.name) as n
MATCH (h)--(n)
RETURN h,n

but am running into:

Type mismatch: n defined with conflicting type List<T> (expected Node):  "MATCH (h)--(n)"

Comment: @sectechguy you need virtual nodes/edges for that (the result doesn't exist in your graph. Have a look at https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/3.4/virtual/